# Lucene.net Exception not logged on productive system

Tags: logging, sitecore, log4net, sitecore7

we have a search implemented and there are some cases where we run into a TooManyClausesException, for example, if we use too many keywords in our search input field. I am not asking how to fix this, its a setting in the Sitecore.ContentSearch.Lucene.DefaultIndexConfiguration.config.

However, on my local machine I can see the exception in the log:

> 24084 09:41:40 ERROR Could not create search context.
>   Exception: Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq.Lucene.Exceptions.TooManyClausesException

On our production system, this exception does not appear in the log. The log levels are the same as on my local machine.

By disassembling the Sitecore.ContentSearch I have seen that this exception is caught and thrown again:

```
          try
      {
        query1 = query1.Rewrite(reader);
      }
      catch (BooleanQuery.TooManyClauses ex)
      {
        throw new TooManyClausesException();
      }
```

Any idea, why this exception just gets "swallowed" on our production environment, I have the feeling it is a configuration issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following statement

```
<setting name="ContentSearch.LuceneQueryClauseCount" value="1024" />
```

from the config file **Sitecore.ContentSearch.Lucene.DefaultIndexConfiguration.config**. It may differs from the one you have on local machine and production. You may also check the following link for more information: [Link](https://sitecorebasics.wordpress.com/2014/06/04/sitecore-7-2-upgrade-learnings/)